# confusing message of correct version of npm

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm

I am very new to the `npm`, I straight away started with `vue`.

I previously had older version of NPM and now while I was working on a vue project I upgraded npm to `6.5.0-next.0`.

Now when I try to build my vue project using `npm run build` I get an error message saying:

```
> node build/build.js


To use this template, you must update following to modules:

  npm: 6.5.0-next.0 should be >= 3.0.0

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! clinic@1.0.0 build: `node build/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the clinic@1.0.0 build script.
```

it says `should be >= 3.0.0` isn't 6.5 already greater than `3.0`

Comment: `-next.0` specifies the pre-release version. Update the npm to stable 6.5.0. This should solve the issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just install npm latest stable version

`npm i -g npm@latest`

or

`sudo npm i -g npm@latest`

Comment: I am giving it a try, looks like it worked was it due to beta version I had it installed earlier ?

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz do not use beta versions

Comment: Worked for me as well